# Multi-stage build with Nvidia container

Tags: docker, nvidia

I would like to flatten a docker image by using docker multi-stage. My Dockerfile is something like this:

```
FROM nvcr.io/nvidia/l4t-tensorrt:r8.2.1-runtime as build

# ...

FROM scratch
COPY --from=build / /
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

However if I try to run this image (even if I use `--runtime nvidia`), the Nvidia libraries will not be mounted at runtime. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by adding `ENV` instruction to the latest stage. The variables can be retrieved with `docker inspect nvcr.io/nvidia/l4t-tensorrt:r8.2.1-runtime`